# Qt 5 (Qt Quick) MenuItem shows up blank most of the time

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, qt-quick

I'm working on a OneDrive client for Linux built with Qt 5.3 + QtQuick UI controls. The issue I'm having is that MenuItem controls, after being activated, only draw fully every few attempts. Basically, clicking "File" in the Menu either produces a MenuItem called "Exit" or it shows up completely blank (white background, no text, no functionality). The issue shows itself very inconsistently. Sometimes it will do it 90% of the time or other times it will only show up 10-20% but in either case it's noticeable and annoying.

The whole project repository can be found at https://github.com/01000101/onedrive-linux-client/ but I've pasted one of the sections that has this issue. I'm using Qt Creator if that provides any hints. Dynamically generated menus (such as the one I also use for a right-click context menu) also is plagued by this.

```
Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64
Kernel: 3.13.0-34-generic
GCC: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
```

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: page_auth
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 480
    color: "#343434"
    title: qsTr("OneDrive Linux Client")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("Help")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("About")
                onTriggered: messageDialog.open()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Unity's global menus?  If so, you might try disabling them.

Comment: Nope, local window menus are enabled. IIRC global menus are disabled by default in 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41181). We have the same problem in our software. You can do nothing about it but wait.